# How to use proc_macro in normal module

Tags: rust

I have some code from hex_literal crate and it look like this:

```rust
#[proc_macro]
pub fn hex(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ts = TokenStream::from_iter(TokenTreeIter::new(input));
    TokenStream::from(TokenTree::Group(Group::new(Delimiter::Bracket, ts)))
}
```

This code won't compile with error:

```
error: the `#[proc_macro]` attribute is only usable with crates of the `proc-macro` crate type
```

Question: how to re-write this macro in normal module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: how to re-write this macro in normal module?

It sounds a bit like you're asking how you can express it as a macro in a "normal" module. Which I interpret as using `macro_rules`, given that the `hex` proc macro is simply adding `[...]` square brackets around the input.

You can easily do that with `macro_rules!` like this:

```rust
macro_rules! hex {
    ($($tt:tt)*) => {
        [$($tt)*]
    };
}
```

---

Otherwise, as [@MaxV already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65815800/2470818) you need to create a separate crate and specify `proc-macro = true`.

Just to give a short an straightforward example. First, let's consider the following `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "proc"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = []
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "hex"
path = "src/hex.rs"
proc-macro = true

[[bin]]
name = "bin"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies]
syn = "1.0"
```

Then you create `src/hex.rs`, with the code you provided (just including the missing use declarations):

```rust
use proc_macro::{Delimiter, Group, TokenStream, TokenTree};
use std::iter::FromIterator;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn hex(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ts = TokenStream::from_iter(input.into_iter());
    TokenStream::from(TokenTree::Group(Group::new(Delimiter::Bracket, ts)))
}
```

Then to use it, you can create `src/main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = hex::hex!(1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6);
}
```

Which expands to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = [1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6];
}
```

Comment: The problem is, i don't want to create another crate, just want that code in a module. But i guess that isn't supported right now.

Comment: @WilliamTaylor Yes, that is not supported. However, with the solution I provided, you can easily have both `main.rs` and `hex.rs` in the same `src/` directory. You also only need the single `Cargo.toml` file, instead of having 1 for a workspace, and 2 for the library and binary crates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separated crate with

```
[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

You can't put `proc-macro` implementation into regular crate.

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713877/why-do-proc-macros-have-to-be-defined-in-proc-macro-crate)